# Node.js selenium webdriver - Get browser capabilities inside test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver on node.js (currently via webdriverio, but I don't mind switching to webdriverjs or wd).

I run some tests on different browsers and want to save results of each test along with information about the browser, for example:

- Test 1 - chrome - 199 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
- Test 1 - IE9 - 199 assertions, 0 failures, 0 skipped
- etc..

How can I get the "desiredCapabilities" object from within the test?

Or how can I pass it to the test so it will be available?

**EDIT**

I found that `browser.desiredCapabilities` returns the requested capabilities object, but now I realize I actually need the "actual capabilities" used (for example if I ask for IE8 on a machine that only has IE11 I get IE11 but the desiredCapabilities object shows version=8).

I'm looking for a way to get the actual used browser capabilities, as documented on [selenium wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities):

> If a session cannot support a capability that is requested in the
>   desired capabilities, no error is thrown; a read-only capabilities
>   object is returned that indicates the capabilities the session
>   actually supports.

Answer (score 5):

Using [WebDriverJS](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) (which you mentioned you could switch to), you can use `getCapabilities`:

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
    console.log(caps);
});
```

The code above will just dump the capabilities but you should use the methods of the [`Capabilities` class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_Capabilities.html) to inspect the values. For instance:

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
    console.log(caps.get("browserName"), caps.get("version"));
});
```

Comment: I get TypeError: Object #<WebdriverIO> has no method 'getCapabilities'.
Which implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm using [WebDriverJS](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs). Looking back at your question now, I realize you mention webdriverio at the top. I missed that.